# $S_n$ contains elements of order $k$ where $k \le n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

What is the easiest way to see that if $k \le n$, then $S_n$ contains elements of order $k$?

Comment: Think about cycles.

Comment: $S_n$ contains a cycle of order $n$, and contains a copy of $S_{n-1}$, so prove by induction

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments above, you can always consider cycles $(1,2, \cdots, k) $.